# Tkinter Limit Size Of Popup per line

Tags: python, popup, tkinter, size, line

Good Day All!

I am trying to figure out how to limit the popup box shown bellow. I am not trying to trim the text, I am however trying to set the amount of characters in the popup per line.
eg: 30 Characters per line in the popup box

`tkMessageBox.showinfo("Results", str(e))`

Any suggestions, without modifying the text itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative would be to subclass the message box and add your own `wraplength` option. This might not suit your needs as is, it doesn't account for spaces in your string:

```
class WrappedBox(object):
    def __init__(self, title, message, wraplength=60):
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
        self.wraplength = wraplength

        self.messageWrapped = '\n'.join([self.message[i:i+self.wraplength] for i in xrange(0,len(self.message),self.wraplength)])

        tkMessageBox.showinfo(self.title, self.messageWrapped)

WrappedBox("Results", str(e), wraplength=30)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do with the tkMessageBox. You either have to alter the text or create your own message window. The latter isn't very difficult -- a `Toplevel`, a `Text` widget with a scrollbar, and a couple of buttons is about all you need.